# Why my headrule width does not appear to change?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

When I run the following script I cannot observe any difference between the width of the line made via `\headrulewidth}{1pt}` and `\headrulewidth}{0.1pt}`. Why is this?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{thesis}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}  
\pagestyle{fancy}
\leftmark
\rhead{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Title chapter}
bla bla bla
\section{Title section}
bla bla bla
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've corrected some of the obvious mistakes you've made in your code: `\chapter{<name>}` not `\chapter(<name>)` (same for `\section`). Also, don't use underscores in the title, since they will cause problems with your current use. ...also, using `\leftmark` in the preamble makes no sense. Finally we don't have `thesis.cls` so can't know whether the class is doing something that doesn't agree with your use of [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fanychdr). Could you supply us with something that reproduces your problem and we can compile on our end?

Answer (score 2):

A try with Google to find your used document class `thesis.cls` shows that there a several possibilitys. Too much to download and test them all!

If your MWE works **not** with a standard class like `article` or `book` or KOMA-Script `scrartcl` or `scrbook` please **always** tell us where to find the used document class!

So I decided to change the document class to `article` to show you how you could change the `\headrulewidth`.  Try the following MWE (and see my changes marked with `<=======`).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}% thesis  % <==============================

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{Test}                           % <==============================
\rhead{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{4.4pt}%0.4 % <============================

\begin{document}
\chapter{Title chapter}
bla bla bla
\section{Title section}
bla bla bla
\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image]

I deleted your useless command `\leftmark` and changed the rule width to 4.4pt as you can see.

If you use document class `thesis` and you get then no thicker rule your document class does not use `\headrulewidth` or just use not package `fancyhdr`.  Just check your `.log` file for error messages or warnings.

Without knowing your used document class we can not do more for you.